# Can a creature sacrifice itself?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have [Quagmire Druid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quagmire%20Druid) as my only Creature. My opponent has [Curse of the Bloody Tome](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Curse%20of%20the%20Bloody%20Tome). Can I use [Quagmire Druid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quagmire%20Druid) to destroy [Curse of the Bloody Tome](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Curse%20of%20the%20Bloody%20Tome), sacrificing itself?

Comment: It may be useful to think of it like this: _you_ sacrifice the creature, it's not the creature that sacrifices itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it doesn't say "sacrifice another," like [Blazing Hellhound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blazing%20Hellhound), you are permitted to sacrifice [Quagmire Druid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quagmire%20Druid) to pay for its effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You could sacrifice it.  It goes like this:

1. Use the ability
2. Pay the price for the ability
3. Then, the ability gets activated

However, the ability activates independent of the card, so if the creature dies in the cost, the ability still happens.  However, for some cards, you can't do this, because the ability is still tied to the card, so if it says "sacrifice another creature", it wouldn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "because the ability is still tied to the card"? What sort of ability are you thinking of?

Comment: The steps are imprecise. 1. The Player announces they are activating the ability, 2. The ability is created on the stack as an object that isn't a card, 3. The target is declared, 4. Is the target legal, 5. Costs are determined (Green Mana, tap the druid, sacrifice a creature), 6. Costs are paid. 7. The ability exists on the stack.

That isn't why "sacrifice another creature" doesn't work; you are simply prohibited from using that creature for the cost.